# A few questions about vector bundles on an algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective complex variety and $E$ an algebraic vector bundle on $X$.

(Q1) If $E$ is globally generated and $c_1(E)=0$ does it follows that $E$ is trivial?

(Q2) If $E$ is globally generated and $Q$ is a quotient of $E$, is $Q$ also globally generated?

(Q3) If $E$ is globally generated, $Q$ is a quotient of $E$ and $H^0(E^\ast)=0$, then must $Q$ be non-trivial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1 and 2, the answer is yes, depending on what you mean by $c_1$ of course. In 3, I do not know what $F$ is.

2 is trivial, since globally generated just means there exists a surjection $G\to E$, where $G$ is trivial. Then, obviously taking composite you get a surjection $G\to Q$.

1 is not difficult either. If rank of $E$ is $r$ and $E$ is globally generated, then taking $r$ general sections you can get an inclusion $G\to E$ where $G$ is a trivial bundle of rank $r$. Taking determinants, you get an inclusion $\Lambda^r G\to \Lambda^r E$. So, if you mean by $c_1(E)=0$ to mean that $\Lambda^rE=\mathcal{O}_X$, then the above inclusion has to be an isomorphism and thus the original map $G\to E$ must also be an isomorphism.

Of course, most definitions would imply that a globally generated line bundle with $c_1=0$ is just $\mathcal{O}_X$.

With your edit, in 3, if $Q\neq 0$ and trivial, then so is $Q^∗$ and it is a subsheaf of $E^∗$ and so $H^0(E^∗)\neq 0$. I assume when you say trivial, it is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_X^r$ for $r$ the rank. If $Q$ is trivial, so is $Q^*$ and non-zero means it has non-zero sections.

Comment: In 3 that was a typo I meant the dual of $E$. Let me edit.

Comment: With your edit, in 3, if $Q\neq 0$ and trivial, then so is $Q^*$ and it is a subsheaf of $E^*$ and so $H^0(E^*)\neq 0$.

Comment: Great. Thank you for your explanations Mohan. Very helpful.

Comment: There is something I don't understand. In 1, you say there is an injection $O^r\to E$. Why is this? I understand that globally generated means a surjection $O^k\to E$ for $k$ large enough. But why can we take an injection when $k$ is the rank of $E$?

Comment: Once you have a surjection $\mathcal{O}^k\to E$, restrict to a point $x$ to get a surjection $k(x)^k\to E\otimes k(x)=k(x)^r$. So, you can find $e_1,\ldots, e_r$, part of a basis of $\mathcal{O}_X^k$ which restricted to $x$ gives an isomorphism to $E\otimes k(x)$. So, we get $\mathcal{O}_X^r\to E$, which is an isomorphism restricted to $x$ and then easy to check that this map is an inclusion.